# Duda sobre el manejo de compras y ventas de productos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mi duda esta en que si tengo una tabla de productos y una de inventario, en esta se guardara la cantidad de producto que tengo en total, pero en la tabla de productos se guardara cada producto sin importar que sea el mismo?
osea, si compro 50 refrescos y X proveedor, tendre 50 registros de refrescos en la tabla de productos?

Más que todo lo digo por la fecha de vencimiento que le debo poner al producto que compro y si solo actualizo la cantidad en la tienda entonces no podre saber cuando vence dicho producto.

y si es de esta forma, entonces al vender productos se eliminaran de la tabla de productos la cantidad que vendi?

Como se maneja la venta y compra de productos?

Comment: 50 registros de refrescos... nooooo. ¿Y si fuera una gran distribuidora... millones de registros de refrescossss? Nooo.  Tendrías quizá que agregar a la tabla `inventario` o a otra tabla, depende... una columna llamada `id_lote` o algo así. Imagino que los productos se compran por lotes, y cada lote tiene una fecha de vencimiento. Por supuesto, necesitarás también una tabla `lotes`.  En la tabla `productos` tus productos deben ser únicos.

Comment: Entonces si tengo una tabla lote en la cual guardar la cantidad de productos que compre, entonces al momento de vender le restaría la cantidad al lote, ¿la suma de los lotes que contienen un producto es el stock de ese producto?, entonces si tengo 2 lotes con el mismo producto, ejemplo, un lapiz, si en el lote 1 tengo una cantidad de 4 y en el lote 2 una cantidad de 8, si quiero vender 6 lapices entonces el lote 1 quedaria en 0 y el lote 2 quedaria con 6?

Comment: ¡Exactamente! Además en la cadena de salida pones los productos más viejos, claro, son los primeros que deberías vender. También esa tabla te serviría para saber los productos que están próximos a su fecha de vencimiento (para aplicar un descuento especial), los productos vencidos para sacarlo de stock, etc, etc.

Comment: Gracias!, tomando en cuenta lo de la tabla de lotes ahora tengo una idea más clara de lo que hare!! Saludos!

Comment: De nada, es sólo una idea muy somera de un diseño que podría ser más complejo... lo importante es tener las ideas claras y recordar siempre algunos principios básicos, como la no redundancia de datos, la forma de agruparlos, consultarlos, analizarlos de la mejor manera posible, etc. Saludos.